# fit weibull modified in R 3 parameter

Tags: r, nls, model-fitting

I want to fit the following data to a Weibull distribution multiplied by a.

datos: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zVAK25kgi25G56eAhOV8LfH4sbesTCrr)

```
                          y=b1*(1-exp(-(x/b2)^b3)
```

However, I could not find a solution using the nls function in R.
Could someone guide me down the path to follow in order to find a solution?

The code used is the following:

```
ajuste_cg<-nls(y~b1*(-exp(-((x/b2)^b3))),data=d,start=list(b1=1000,b2=140,b3=20), trace=T,control = list(maxiter=10000000))
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do.  Are you in fact trying to fit a nonlinear time series model (i.e. x is time, y is the amount of something)?  It doesn't seem to make much sense to fit a Weibull, and your formula isn't really a Weibull. Also, the formula that you have gives *negative* values for the starting parameters you suggest.  Can you give some more context please?  How did you choose the starting values?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the package `survival`. It is made for implementing parametric survival regressions (Weibull models included, of course). Here's the code:

```
library(survival)

weibull_model = survreg(Surv(time, event) ~ expalatory_variables, dist="weibull")
```

The `Surv()` object that you see instead of a `y` is an R "survival object", and works like your dependent variable in a survival regression. The `time` and `event` variables must represent duration and event occurrence (0 or 1), respectively.
Please replace `explanatory_variables` with your appropriate set of variables.